# OpenCV search for сontours

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network

How do I find only the сontours of the characters?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C26Yz.jpg)

```
img = cv2.imread('C:\\output5.jpg')

 # grayscale
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 cv2.waitKey(0)

 # binarize
 ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
# find contours
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
 # sort contours
 sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
# Get bounding box
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

# Getting ROI
roi = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]

# show ROI
# cv2.imwrite('roi_imgs.png', roi)
cv2.imshow('charachter' + str(i), roi)
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (90, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('marked areas', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)>quote
```

I find not only symbols,but also words,words in frames, and I only need symbols for further recognition by the neural network.

Comment: Hey and welcome to StackOverflow! Since the image you provided has some characters touching one another, there's no trivial way to separate them into separate characters without prior knowledge (= human annotation or some other trained model). You can try using an existing OCR software to extract boxes around each letter, and then find the contour inside the box - see https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/pytesseract.py#L381 for example on finding boxes in an image.

Comment: I find symbols, but also words, etc., how can I leave only the outlines of symbols?https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html   I find сontours hierarchy,but I don't know how to use it.